# How to integrate Flingo-API in Android

Tags: android, flingo

I want integrate Flingo-API in Android.

here is the [link](http://flingo.org/developers.html)

Did any one know about this Filngo API integraion.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.send2tv

It uses the flingo API.

There are a lot of things that it could do... If you are interested go to flingo.org and post to the forum.